# Android DatePicker month as integer

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a simple question but after searching a while I couldn't find the answer yet. In a DatePicker, is it possible to change the month to be displayed as an integer not a string?.eg: {1,2,3..} not {jan,feb,mar...}

**EDIT:**

Although @kaneda's solution seems to work, in android 3.0 at least the methods and attributes are not the same. The code I'm using is this:

```
public DatePickerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       Field[] fields = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
       try {
           for (Field field : fields) {
               field.setAccessible(true);
               if (TextUtils.equals(field.getName(), "mMonthSpinner")) {
                   Method m =     field.getType().getDeclaredMethod("setDisplayedValues", String[].class);
                   m.setAccessible(true);
                   String[] s = new String[]     {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
                   Object[] params = new Object[1];
                   params[0] = s;
                   m.invoke(field.get(this), params);
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Best solution, is to create a Custom DatePicker (following @kaneda first advice), will always work without compatibility issues and not relaying on reflection.

Used the [date_picker.xml](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/layout/date_picker.xml.shtml) from android and DatePicker.java posted by @kaneda. Also, I used a custom NumberPicker (because the one the DatePicker widget uses is internal to android). For the NumberPicker widget I followed this [link](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5).

In the CustomDatePicker I commented the function `getShortMonths()` and set the month range as `mMonthPicker.setRange(1, NUMBER_OF_MONTHS);`.

Comment: have u got the answer.can u please send me the source code for the datepicker which shows months in integer.please send the source code to rubanb.tech@gmail.com  .else post as answer below

Comment: @Ruban, I don't have it anymore as it was for my work and i've changed job. Nevertheless, you should be able to implement it based on the answer and comments.

Comment: tks for ur reply . i have created my own date picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what concerns best practices I think it's the most correct and easier for you if you create your own custom `DatePicker` by creating your own layout, so I suggest you take a look at its source code just for reference:

[Android Source Code](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

or

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.2_r1/android/widget/DatePicker.java)

That's the fancy way. The ugly way, you could do this:

**Android Version < 3.0**

```
package my.pkg;
...
class MyDatePicker extends DatePicker {

    public MyDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Field[] fields = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        try {
            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (TextUtils.equals(field.getName(), "mMonthPicker")) {
                    Method m = field.getType().getDeclaredMethod("setRange", int.class, int.class, String[].class);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    String[] s = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
                    m.invoke(field.get(this), 1, 12, s);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Android Version >= 3.0 (only the constructor)**

```
public MyDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Field[] fields = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    try {
        String[] s = new String[] {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"};
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (TextUtils.equals(field.getName(), "mMonthSpinner")) {
                NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker) field.get(this);
                monthPicker.setDisplayedValues(s);
            } 
            if (TextUtils.equals(field.getName(), "mShortMonths")) {
                field.set(this, s);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then the boilerplate xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <my.pkg.MyDatePicker
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Great!, thank you very much!, I was thinking the way was to develop my own DatePicker.

Comment: The solution works great but I had to change the constructor a bit to make it work in my environment. The month attribute is 'mMonthSpinner' (I'm using android 3.0) and the NumberPicker method is 'setDisplayedValues'. I edited the question.

Comment: @marbarfa I'm glad my answer could help you on the way. In fact, if your using android 3.0 (hence, Api level 11), it's even easier because  the Android SDK gives you access to the `NumberPicker` class. I updated my answer. Thank you for the remark! Good luck!