# Capitalize First Letter of Month in datePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have my datePicker in my app and in English language the first letter of the month is in Uppercase. when I change my device language into Español it turn into lowercase. Just like enero, febrero, marso ... and so on. I wanted to Capitalize the first letter of the month

```
datePicker.init(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth() + 1, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String str=datePicker.getMonth().tostring;
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        str = Character.toString(str.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+str.substring(1);
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer but I already tried that. It is actually change the month but the datePicker ignore the format of that string to int. it says that "Enero" is invalid int.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently months in Spanish are not supposed to be capitalized, so what you are seeing is the proper case.  [Studyspanish.com](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/months.htm)

Comment: So it is not possible to customize my datePicker month displayed?

Comment: it is Incorrect to Display the month in a Wrong case.

Comment: If you still want to do it you could use reflection to change the strings in the DatePicker.  See the answer in this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505691/android-datepicker-month-as-integer)

Comment: Or create your own DatePicker class as also described in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505691/android-datepicker-month-as-integer)