# Spinner DatePicker with numeric months instead of named

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

I have a basic `DatePicker` that's spinner-style, without any layouts. It looks like this:

```
class DatePickerFragment: DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private lateinit var date: Date

    interface Callbacks {
        fun onDateSelected(date: Date)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        date = arguments?.getSerializable(ARG_DATE) as Date
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            time = date
        }

        val initialYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val initialMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val initialDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        return DatePickerDialog(
            requireContext(),
            this,
            initialYear,
            initialMonth,
            initialDay
        )
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        val selectedDate = GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth).time
        targetFragment?.let { fragment ->
            (fragment as Callbacks).onDateSelected(selectedDate)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(date: Date): DatePickerFragment {
            return DatePickerFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private const val ARG_DATE = "date"
```

The picker works as it should. The problem is that it displays the month name (three letter format), see:

[image]

**How do I make the DatePicker to display months numerically (two-digit format)?** In other words instead of `Mar` it would display as `03`. Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to implement custom spinners, if possible.

Comment: the screenshot will be helpful, what is there and what you want to achieve. I guess you want to change Mar to 03 on calendar right?

Comment: @HappySingh yes, that is correct.

Comment: @HappySingh DatePicker, the spinner one, not the calendar view, to be precise.

Comment: You need to get month picker id. Try it with `view?.findViewById<NumberPicker?>(resources.getIdentifier("android:id/month", null, null))?.displayedValues = arrayOf("01","02" ....)` at `onDateChanged(...)`

Comment: @StanislavBondar unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of the components?

Comment: @HappySingh what components?

Comment: which text view you want to changes

Comment: @HappySingh it's both in my post and in the comment. I want to change the months. Right now they in shortened text form, I want them to be in two-digit number format. The code is literally all there is to my DatePicker. There's nothing else.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505691/android-datepicker-month-as-integer

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190316/display-month-fields-in-datepickerdialog-in-numeric-format-instead-of-alphabetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by finding the month NumberPicker from DatePicker and setting the displayed values to numeric strings.

Make the below changes:

1.Create your DatePickerDialog in `onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` using a custom Style like below:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            time = date
        }

        val initialYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val initialMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val initialDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        val mPickerDialog: DatePickerDialog = object : DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), R.style.MyDatePickerDialogStyle, this, initialYear, initialMonth, initialDay) {
            override fun onDateChanged(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
                super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, dayOfMonth)
                setNumericMonth(view)
            }
        }
        setNumericMonth(mPickerDialog.datePicker)
        return mPickerDialog
    }
```

where `R.style.MyDatePickerDialogStyle` is a custom style to set the Spinner Style like below:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
      <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
    
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
     <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
 </style>
```

2.Use the below helper functions in `DatePickerFragment` to set month to be numeric like below:

```
private fun setNumericMonth(datePicker: DatePicker) {
        val monthNumbers = arrayOf("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")
        val monthPicker = getMonthNumberPicker(datePicker)
        if (monthPicker != null) {
            monthPicker.displayedValues = monthNumbers
        }
    }

private fun getMonthNumberPicker(datePicker: DatePicker?): NumberPicker? {
        try {
            if (datePicker != null && datePicker.childCount > 0 && datePicker.getChildAt(0) is ViewGroup) {
                val vg = datePicker.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
                if (vg.childCount > 0 && vg.getChildAt(0) is ViewGroup) {
                    val vgPickers = vg.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
                    for (i in 0 until vgPickers.childCount) {
                        if (vgPickers.getChildAt(i) is NumberPicker && i == 1) {
                            return vgPickers.getChildAt(i) as NumberPicker
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        return null
    }
```

**Result:**

[image: date_numeric_month_picker]

Comment: I will have to study how `getMonthNumberPicker()` works under the hood. But your solution works, thank you.

Comment: you are welcome. getMonthNumberPicker() tries to find the Month Number Picker which is a child of a LinearLayout ViewGroup (vgPickers). This LinearLayout has 3 NumberPickers children, the first its the day Number Picker, the second which we are interested is the month (i==1 in code) and the year NumberPicker.